# App icon not shown with Game Center Messages invite image

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

As you likely know, Game Center new player invites are done through Messages now in iOS 10. When using the custom invite image, GKMessageImage.png, the GK view controller generated message is supposed to also insert a tiny app icon in the upper left corner. Yet in my problematic case, it is the null criss-crossy icon when using my iPhone 6S to compose the invite message, even though I have provided all seemingly relevant app icons to XCode (every size asked for in Image.xcassets/AppIcon for iOS 9 and 10, the only versions my app works on). Oddly, it works properly when I compose the message from an iPad. Has anyone seen or solved this? Is there some other place, filename, and/or size that would be needed to provide this app icon?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: It went away. I think it happened after I deleted all of my icons and then readded them. However, I'm not sure exactly why it happened in the first place and I wouldn't be surprised if this solution isn't reproducible. I sent Apple support my code and they were able to see the problem on their devices. They said it was a bug and were not able to fix it.